# Error `No handles with labels` when trying to relocate geopandas legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, geopandas

My plot works fine as long as I do not attempt to change the location of its legend. (I am plotting a GeoDataFrame.)

```
# %%
ax = NE_shp.plot(column=NE_shp.iloc[:,4], figsize=(10,3), scheme='quantiles', edgecolor='k', k=10, legend=True)

#ax.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1)) #This is the line for relocating legend

ax.set_title('The Map', fontsize=16)
ax.axis('off')
```

the resulted figure:
[image: without legend position setting]

But when I use the line that now is masked as a comment, to change the legend position, it gives the following error and the legend is not shown as the figure below

`No handles with labels found to put in legend.`

[image: After setting a position for legend]

(I suspect if it has something to do with `scheme='quantiles'` cause it is not inherent of matplotlib and is added by pySAL.)

Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Comment: [Get them before trying to move It](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html) - `handles, labels = x.get_legend_handles_labels(); ax.legend(handles, labels)`

Comment: @wwii if that worked, calling `ax.legend` would as well, right? Or inversely put, because `ax.get_legend_handles_labels` returns an empty list, `ax.legend()` does not produce a legend.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest … ahh well I guess that makes sense. Using a toy DataFrame, OP's code works.

Comment: @wwii Even with a toy data frame it will not work out of the box. See mwe below.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest .. Sorry was working with a Pandas DataFrame to see what might be going on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`GeoDataFrame.plot`](http://geopandas.org/reference.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.plot) provides a **`legend_kwds`** argument, which expects a dictionary. This dictionary will be passed on to either `.legend` or `.colorbar`, depending on what kind of plot you produce. So the arguments `loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1)` will need to go into that dictionary like

```
gdf.plot(..., legend=True, legend_kwds=dict(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1)))
```

Complete runnable example:

```
import geopandas as gpd
print(gpd.__version__)   ## 0.5
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres')) 
gdf['quant']=np.random.rand(len(gdf))*100-20

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,4))
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.7)
gdf.plot(column='quant', scheme='quantiles', edgecolor='k', k=10, 
         legend=True, legend_kwds=dict(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1)), ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked very well. Just a follow up. Where can I find all related arguments that I can use to control the legend? (for example, the right part of each label in the legend is not needed. I am looking for a way to remove the right side).   again

Comment: Oh. I think I found them [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html)